# How to delete a dependent model from the same collection in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views, backbone-events, backbone-relational

I have a model which has both navid and subnavid .While destroying a model i need to check in the entire collection , for other models which have navid as same as subnavid of the model i'am trying to delete . Please help me out . Thanks in advance . Heregoes my sample code.

> Model:
>
> var Node = Backbone.Model.extend({
>       defaults: {
>           NavId: '',
>           SubNavId: ''.
>           ItemName:''
>       } }
>
> Collection:
>
> var NodeCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({    model:Node }
>
> And i have two view one for the Node(i am building tr) and other for
>   the collection(I need to build table) var NodeCollectionView =
>   Backbone.View.extend({
>
> ```
> initialize: function (options) {
>     var self = this;      self.collection = new NodeCollection({ NavigationId: options.NavigationId });
>     self.collection.fetch({
>         success: function () {
>             /*I am getting  hte proper collection from my restful api and iam able to bind it properly
>           self.render();
>         }
>     });
> },
>
> render: function () {
>     var that = this;
>     _.each(this.collection.models, function (item) {
>         that.RenderEachNode(item);
>     }, this);
> },
>
> RenderEachNode: function (item) {
>     var TempJsonNode = item.toJSON();
>     var self = this;
>     var nodeView = new NodeView({
>         tagName: 'tr',
>         id: 'NavId_' + TempJsonNode.NavItemId,
>         model: item
>     });
> } });
> ```

```
var ItemTemplate = ""; ItemTemplate += "    <td>"; ItemTemplate += "        <a><%= ItemName %></a>"; ItemTemplate +="   </td>"; ItemTemplate
+=" <td>"; ItemTemplate +="         <a href='#' original-title='Delete ' class='tip_north Delete'>X</a>"; ItemTemplate +="  </td>  ";           


var NavigationItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: ItemTemplate,
    render: function () {
        var self = this;
        var tmpl = _.template(this.template);
        this.$el.html(tmpl(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },
    events: {
        "click .Delete": "DeleteBtnClick"
    },
    DeleteBtnClick: function () {
        var self = this;
        self.model.destroy({
            success: function (status, data) {
                var RetData = JSON.parse(data);
                if (RetData.Status == 'Success') {
                    $(self.el).remove()
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error In Deleting The Record');
            }
        });
        return false;
    } });
```

I am able to build the table properly but while destroying a model , i am not figuring out a way to destroy the dependent models.My Api is restricted in such a way that i cannot get a nested json ( if so i would have done with backbone relation). so i need to figure out some way that  the other models and views  which has the NavId of the model am deleting.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like:

```
var NodeView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    //when the model gets destroyed, remove the view
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'destroy', this.remove);
  },
  //..clip
  DeleteBtnClick: function () {
    var self = this;
    var collection = self.model.collection;
    var navId = self.model.get('NavId');

    self.model.destroy({
      success: function (status, data) {
        var RetData = JSON.parse(data);
        if (RetData.Status == 'Success') {
          //if parent was part of a collection
          if (collection) {
            //find related models
            var related = collection.filter(function (model) {
              return model.get('SubNavId') === navId;
            });

            //call destroy for each related model.
            var promises = _.invoke(related, 'destroy');

            //optional: if you want to do something when all the children
            //are destroyed:
            $.when.apply($, promises).then(function () {
              console.log('all destroyed');
            });
          }
        }
      },
      error: function () {
        console.log(arguments);
        alert('Error In Deleting The Record');
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
});
```

**Edit:** [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qhTfM/)

Comment: Hi Fencliff iam new to backbone js i will prepare a quik fiddle can you please modify thatand show me?

Comment: @ArunKumar, I can take a look. If I can do it in short amount of time, I will.

Comment: @ArunKumar, JSFiddle is being really slow. I'll take a look at this later, when I have time.

Comment: @ArunKumar, added a fiddle in the post and updated the code. Hope this helps.

Comment: iam not able to find any changes in the fiddle

Comment: @ArunKumar, check the link in my answer.

Comment: thanks for the code provided . but one small glitch is there in the code for example electronics is of root if i remove the electronics then all the tr should delte . but that is not working it is working only upto one level.

Comment: @ArunKumar, oh. I'm no longer in front of my computer, and won't be for a while. You need to move the removal logic to the model level, methinks.

Comment: ok i will try that . thank you very much for the help provided . if iam not able to do that i will get back to you . thankyou

Comment: Hi i tried what you told me and now iam able to generate the list and delte as i expected . Thanks for the help .. Now i have other require ment where the bindind of tr will have a sequnce .. based on sequnce i need to find the tr for which i have to append the newly genarated tr html...

Comment: @ArunKumar, maybe open another question about that? And please mark this one accepted, if it works.

Comment: plza check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769378/how-to-make-a-dynamic-el-in-backbone-biew